# R: Converting a Single Loop into a Double Loop

Tags: r, loops

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
set.seed(123)
my_data1 = data.frame(var1 =  rnorm(500,100,100), prop = runif(500, min=0, max=0.5))
my_data2 = data.frame(var1 = rnorm(500, 200, 50), prop = runif(500, min=0.4, max=0.7))
my_data = rbind(my_data1, my_data2)
```

I made ten equal-sized bins, found the average proportion within each bin, then plotted the results:

```
final = my_data %>%
arrange(var1) %>%
mutate(ntile = ntile(var1, 10)) %>%
group_by(ntile) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(prop))

plot(final$ntile, final$mean, type = "l", xlab = "Bin Number", ylab = "Average Proportion", main = "Relationship Between Bins and Average Proportion")
```

[image]

Now, suppose I:

- Take a random 70% sample, create 10 bins and calculate the mean proportion within each of these bins
- Then, from the remaining 30% sample - I again take a random sample and create 10 bins and calculate the mean proportion within each of the bins
- Next, I take the squared sum of the difference between these two steps for each bin
- Finally, repeat this process many times (while tracking the results)

Below, I wrote some R code for this procedure:

```
base = sample_n(my_data, 700)

base_comp = base %>%
            arrange(var1) %>%
            mutate(ntile = ntile(var1, 10)) %>%
            group_by(ntile) %>%
            summarise(mean = mean(prop))


sampling_frame = my_data %>% anti_join(base)

my_list = list()

for (i in 1:1000)
    
{
    
    a_i = sample_n(sampling_frame, 100)
    
    base_a_i = a_i %>%
    arrange(var1) %>%
    mutate(ntile = ntile(var1, 10)) %>%
    group_by(ntile) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(prop))
    
    sum_i <- sum(map2_dbl(base_a_i$mean, base_comp$mean, function(x, y) (x - y)^2))
    
    my_list[[i]] <- data.frame(id = i, sum_i)
    print(data.frame(id = i, sum_i))
}

results = do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)

plot(density(results$sum_i), main = "Distribution of Deviations")
plot(results$id, results$sum_i, xlab = "Iteration", ylab = "Deviation", main = "Trace Plot", type = "b")
```

[image]

**My Question:** Now, I am trying to create a "double loop" - that is, I would to:

- For j = 1, randomly create "base_j" , "base_comp_j" and "sampling_frame_j"
- Repeat the "i" loop 100 times
- Take the average of all "sum_i" for j=1 (i.e. average_sum_i_j)
- Now, repeat this for j = 2
- Repeat until j = 100
- Each point on these two graphs will be "average_sum_i_j"

**Here is my attempt to do this:**

```
#  change i and j index to 10 for brevity

my_list = list()

for (j in 1:10) {
    base_j = sample_n(my_data, 700)
    base_comp_j = base_j %>%
        arrange(var1) %>%
        mutate(ntile = ntile(var1, 10)) %>%
        group_by(ntile) %>%
        summarise(mean = mean(prop))
    sampling_frame_j = my_data %>% anti_join(base_j)
    sum_i_list = list()
    for (i in 1:10) {
        a_i = sample_n(sampling_frame_j, 100)
        base_a_i = a_i %>%
            arrange(var1) %>%
            mutate(ntile = ntile(var1, 10)) %>%
            group_by(ntile) %>%
            summarise(mean = mean(prop))
        sum_i <- sum(map2_dbl(base_a_i$mean, base_comp_j$mean, function(x, y) (x - y)^2))
        sum_i_list[[i]] <- sum_i
    }
    average_sum_i_j = mean(unlist(sum_i_list))
    my_list[[j]] <- data.frame(id_j = j, id_i = i, average_sum_i_j)
    print(data.frame(id_j = j, id_i = i, average_sum_i_j))
}

results = do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)

plot(density(results$average_sum_i_j), main = "Distribution of Deviations")
plot(results$id, results$average_sum_i_j, xlab = "Iteration", ylab = "Deviation", main = "Trace Plot", type = "b")
```

However, I don't think I am doing this right since the loop does not appear to be cycling through both indices.

**Can someone show me how to correct this?**

Thanks!

Comment: The loop is cycling through both indices but `results` only has as many rows as values of `j` (10 in the example). Your column `id_i` is meaningless since after the loop on `i` you will always have `i == 10` and the `sum_i_list` is averaged. That's why it seems not to be cycling through `i` though it is.

Comment: Also, the last plot's x coordinate is wrong, it should be `results$id_j`.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: thank you for your replies! I have a feeling that I have overcomplicated this question. If you have time, could you please help me out here? thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the question's code revised to correct some, not many, problems it has.
I have commented the changes in the code, the rest should be self-explanatory.
I have also commented out the data.frame printing.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
})

set.seed(123)
my_data1 = data.frame(var1 =  rnorm(500,100,100), prop = runif(500, min=0, max=0.5))
my_data2 = data.frame(var1 = rnorm(500, 200, 50), prop = runif(500, min=0.4, max=0.7))
my_data = rbind(my_data1, my_data2)

# define these constants, it will be easier to change
# them here than in the loops
nbins <- 10L
n_loop_i <- 10L
n_loop_j <- 100L
n_my_data <- nrow(my_data)
sampling_size_j <- 700L
sampling_size_i <- 100L

# create the results list beforehand, much more memory
# and speed efficient
my_list <- vector("list", length = n_loop_j)

for (j in seq.int(n_loop_j)) {
  #
  # avoids an expensive call to anti_join
  # all that is needed is, after the pipe,
  # to negate the index jnx 
  jnx <- sample(n_my_data, sampling_size_j)
  base_j <- my_data[jnx, ]
  base_comp_j <- base_j %>%
    arrange(var1) %>%
    mutate(ntile = ntile(var1, nbins)) %>%
    group_by(ntile) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(prop))
  sampling_frame_j <- my_data[-jnx, ]
  #
  # it's simpler to create and populate a vector
  # than a list and after the i loop it will
  # avoid a function call (unlist)
  sum_i_vec <- numeric(n_loop_i)
  for (i in seq.int(n_loop_i)) {
    a_i <- sample_n(sampling_frame_j, sampling_size_i)
    base_a_i <- a_i %>%
      arrange(var1) %>%
      mutate(ntile = ntile(var1, 10)) %>%
      group_by(ntile) %>%
      summarise(mean = mean(prop))
    sum_i <- sum(map2_dbl(base_a_i$mean, base_comp_j$mean, function(x, y) (x - y)^2))
    sum_i_vec[i] <- sum_i
  }
  average_sum_i_j <- mean(sum_i_vec)
  #
  # I would get rid of id_i = i, it is always the
  # last value of seq.int(n_loop_i)
  my_list[[j]] <- data.frame(id_j = j, id_i = i, average_sum_i_j)
  #print(data.frame(id_j = j, id_i = i, average_sum_i_j))
}

results <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_list)
str(results)
#> 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ id_j           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ id_i           : int  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
#>  $ average_sum_i_j: num  0.0522 0.0266 0.0494 0.0278 0.0244 ...

# save current graphic settings
old_par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(density(results$average_sum_i_j), main = "Distribution of Deviations")
plot(results$id_j, results$average_sum_i_j, 
     xlab = "Iteration", ylab = "Deviation", 
     main = "Trace Plot", type = "b")
```

[image]

```r
# restore graphic settings
par(old_par)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @ Rui Barradas : Thank you so much for your answer! Just a question - what do you think of the "statistical validity" of the approach I have described? Do you think in theory it can detect mild levels of overfitting?

Comment: @stats_noob As a general purpose rule, if the data is continuous don't bin it, you will be loosing information contained in the data. Try to find other methods in the literature that are or seem to be relevant to your subject matter.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: Thank you for your reply! I agree with you that binning can lead to a lot of problems. But for argument sake, suppose you had to create bins for some specific reason - do you think that the approach described in this question is somewhat statistically valid? Is it using principles from statistics (e.g. central limit theorem, law of large numbers, bootstrap, cross validation, etc.) to see if false associations might be initially present within the first graph? Thank you so much!